# swift struct in struct

Tags: swift, uitableview, struct

I have 2 struct:

```
struct HeroStats:Decodable {

    let id: Int
    let count: Int
    let cream: String
    let position: Int
    let info: [HeroMemder]()

}

struct HeroMemder:Decodable  {
    let name: String
    let fio: String
    let color: String
}
```

And in `UIViewcontroller` I want to pass data from HeroMemder Im try like this:

```
var hero:HeroStats?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
nameLbl.text = hero2?.members.name
```

But can't

How can I do this?

Comment: First, you want `let info: [HeroMember]`, without the `()`. (I assume you wanted `HeroMember`, not `HeroMender`.) Or if you want to call this variable `members`, it would be `let members: [HeroMember]`. Second, since `members` is an array, you want to let it know which one you want, e.g., if you want the first one, it would be `nameLbl.text = hero2?.members.first?.name`. Third, or perhaps you didn't mean it to be an array? E.g. `let member: HeroMember`, in which case you'd do `nameLbl.text = hero2?.member.name`.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you a example:

> Your structs

```
struct HeroStats: Decodable {

    let id: Int
    let count: Int
    let cream: String
    let position: Int
    let info: [HeroMember]

}

struct HeroMember: Decodable  {
    let name: String
    let fio: String
    let color: String
}
```

> Here, We are adding the data in the structs:

```
/// This is the heromembers data, we are creating 3 members like that

    let heroMember1 = HeroMember(name: "jogendar", fio: "fioo", color: "red")
    let heroMember2 = HeroMember(name: "Singh", fio: "fioo", color: "yellow")
    let heroMember3 = HeroMember(name: "Choudhary", fio: "fioo", color: "green")

/// This is the HeroStatus struct data, we are adding all 3 members into info in an array format.

    let heroStatusData = HeroStats(id: 1, count: 1, cream: "any", position: 1, info: [heroMember1, heroMember2, heroMember3])
```

> Here, We are getting the data from struct:

```
/// This is first member name 
nameLbl.text = heroStatusData.info.first?.name
```

Or

```
/// This is last member name
  nameLbl.text = heroStatusData.info.last.name
```